# Reputation error in reputation league

Tags: bug, reputation-leagues

My total reputation in the league is shown as 4249, but the year reputation is shown as 4443.

How can the year reputation be greater than total reputation?

I didn't offer any bounty.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The year, quarter, month, and week reputations contain the score of all earned reputations only, even if it was deleted. Whereas **total reputation** is calculating without deleted posts.

The year, quarter, month, and week reputation calculation includes:

- Reputation earned on suggested edits where those posts were subsequently deleted.
- Reputations earned on the migrated posts and removed from the current site.
- Reputations earned on the answers, but the posts were removed by the moderators.

Comment: When checking in that way, I lost more than 300 reputation this year. I tried but the calculation I did is not giving a perfect answer

Comment: Correct, see answer on dupe. (its author was SE developer when writing it, so it's official answer.)